# Set up TeamCity to write Tags to GitHub Repository

Tags: git, github, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have our code in github and teamcity works well pulling changes. Unfortunately when I try and apply the label to the repository I receive the following result:

Labeling process failed: Labelling failed: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Updating the ref refs/tags/EDW_Access_Service-1.0.217 to Tag={ object 9f8217173a32c09bbad280439de4edeaebc47e17 type commit tag EDW_Access_Service-1.0.217 tagger PersonIdent[, , Thu Oct 15 14:12:58 2015 +0100] } failed. ReturnCode from RefUpdate.update() was REJECTED

The user that the VCS is configured with has write access to the repository.

I can't see any reason why this would be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it works fine if I remove the - from the tag name. It seems this is a banned character.